# Populating tabs in Spring Boot Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, twitter-bootstrap-3, thymeleaf

Iam new to Spring Boot-Thymeleaf.

I get my model object from controller and using that object I need to populate 2 sepearate tables
in seperate tabs.

I have managed to get my tabs in place but no idea on how to populate seperate data tables in each tab.

Please help me with this.

```
<div class="row">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link active">Realised Commission</a>
                                                    
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link">Un-realised Commission</a>
            </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have 1 model object that contains all the realised and unrealised commissions? If so, you will need to loop (th:each) over all items in your model object and check if they are realised or unrealised (th:if). You will need to do that twice: once for the realised and once for the unrealised. If the backend can provide 2 model objects, 1 for realised and 1 for unrealised then you can just loop (th:each) over the correct one at the correct place.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it will answer on your question (if not, comment and i will try to help you). You can place information from module anywhere on your page using `th:text="${nameOfObjectFromModule}"`
and others.
Please check official documentation of thymeleaf

Edited (thanks to the commentator below):

https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html

Comment: Just a minor remark: Thymeleaf 3 was released a while years ago. The documentation can be found at https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html